# In ASP.NET Core read JWT token from Cookie instead of Headers

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, asp.net-core, jwt

I am porting an `ASP.NET Web API 4.6 OWIN` application to `ASP.NET Core 2.1`. The application is working based on `JWT` token. But the token in passed via cookie instead of header. I'm not sure why headers are not used, it is just the situation that I have to deal with.

Consider that authentication is not done via cookie. The cookie is just used as a transfering media. In the legacy application `CookieOAuthBearerProvider` is employed to extract `JWT` token from cookie. Configuration code is as like this:

```
    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
        new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            AllowedAudiences = new[] { audienceId },
            IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
            {
                new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, audienceSecret)
            },
            Provider = new CookieOAuthBearerProvider("token")
        });
}
```

`CookieOAuthBearerProvider` class source source code is as follow:

```
public class CookieOAuthBearerProvider : OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
{
    readonly string _name;
    public CookieOAuthBearerProvider(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public override Task RequestToken(OAuthRequestTokenContext context)
    {
        var value = context.Request.Cookies[_name];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            context.Token = value;
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
```

This solution is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25097221/how-to-authenticate-a-access-token-by-owin-oauthbearerauthentication) with more detail.

Now I need to implement similar solution for ASP.NET Core. Problem is that `UseJwtBearerAuthentication` does not exists in `ASP.NET Core` anymore and I do not know how I can introduce a custom AuthenticationProvider.

Any helps is highly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
There is [a solution that tries to validate JWT by its own code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398276/how-can-i-validate-a-jwt-passed-via-cookies). It is not what I need. I'm just searching for a way to pass token recieved from cookie to header reader.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core 2.0, the authentication system was somewhat overhauled. Rather than using e.g. `UseJwtBearerAuthentication` as middleware, ASP.NET Core 2.0+ configures things using DI. For example, this looks something like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options => {
            // ...
        });
}
```

With that out of the way, the next question would be: how do we instruct the JwtBearer authentication process to look at a cookie using this new system?

That `options` object being passed in to `AddJwtBearer` contains an `Events` property of its own, which allows you to customise various parts of the process. Using `OnMessageReceived`, you can achieve what you're looking for:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options => {
            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnMessageReceived = context =>
                {
                    context.Token = context.Request.Cookies["CookieName"];
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });
}
```

By setting `context.Token`, you're telling the JwtBearer process that you've taken care of extracting the token yourself.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x?view=aspnetcore-2.1)'s a useful migration document that explains the authentication changes in more detail.

Comment: would `context.Token` always been null or empty in this scope?  is that why you mean by telling JwtBearer process that you'v taken care f extracting the token yourself?  no processing would occur before or after?

Comment: @BrettCaswell Yes, it'll typically be `null` or empty here. You can trace through the latest GA of the source [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/release/5.0/src/Security/Authentication/JwtBearer/src/JwtBearerHandler.cs#L69) to check it for yourself.