# ASP.NET Core 5 and 6 JWT authentication is always throws HTTP 401 code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to implement JWT-based security in ASP.NET Core. All I want it to do, for now, is to read tokens in the button `@Html.ActionLink("Test","Oper","Home")` , authorize header and validate them against my criteria. I don't know what missed but it is always returning HTTP 401 code.

File `HomeController.cs`

```cs
        private string GenerateJSONWebToken(UserPaul userinfo)
        {
            var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
            var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub,userinfo.Username),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email,userinfo.Email),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti,Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            };
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
                audience: _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
                claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10),
                signingCredentials: credentials
                );
            var encodetoken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
            var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions();         
            cookieOptions.HttpOnly = true;
            cookieOptions.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
            //cookieOptions.Domain = Request.Host.Value;
            cookieOptions.Path = "/";
            Response.Cookies.Append("jwt", encodetoken, cookieOptions);
            return encodetoken;
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            string AccountNumber="TestUser";
            JWTtokenMVC.Models.TestContext userQuery = new JWTtokenMVC.Models.TestContext();
            var query = userQuery.Testxxxx.Where(N => N.UserId ==AccountNumber).FirstOrDefault();
            IActionResult response = Unauthorized();
            if (query != null)
            {
                var tokenStr = GenerateJSONWebToken(query);
                response = Ok(new { token = tokenStr });
            }
            return response;
        }

        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet("Home/Oper")]
        public IActionResult Oper()
        {
            var authenticationCookieName = "jwt";
            var cookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies[authenticationCookieName];
            List<Test_SHOW> sHOWs = new List<Test_SHOW>();
            JWTtokenMVC.Models.Test.TestContext userQuery= new JWTtokenMVC.Models.Test.TestContext();
            var query = userQuery.Test.Select(T => new Test_SHOW
            {number= T.number,name= T.name,mail= T.mail}).OrderBy(o => o.Iid);
            sHOWs.AddRange(query);

            return View("Views/Home/Oper.cshtml", sHOWs);
 
        }
```

This is the **Startup.cs** code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;

namespace JWTtokenMVC
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials().Build());
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {

NameClaimType ="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name",
                   
RoleClaimType = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role",
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"])

                    )
                };

            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "node_modules")),
                RequestPath = "/" + "node_modules"
            });
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs image

[image]

Startup.cs Add UseAuthentication

[image]

Comment: Please do not include code as images. Replace your Startup images with text.

Comment: Please add the setting vales used in the code as wel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I assume you are trying asp.net core with an angular project.I think you are missed adding your client-side URL to your .net core project. `AddCors`on extension call for IServiceCollection just registers all required services, but it does not add Cors middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.So add this code `app.UseCors(x =>  x.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().WithOrigins("https://localhost:4200"));` in your Configure method.i think it's resolve your issue.

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                //clarify code
              
            }
            else{  

               //clarify code    

            }
            

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors(x => 
  x.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().WithOrigins("https://localhost:4200")); //your  client side URL.you are missing this unfortunately

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

           //clarify code
        }
```

**UPDATE**

Install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors`

Just remove `AllowCredentials()`  and it's will fix your issue.

Comment: add code error :
The CORS protocol does not allow specifying a wildcard (any) origin and credentials at the same time. Configure the CORS policy by listing individual origins if credentials needs to be

Comment: error :The connection to the terminal's pty host process is unresponsive, the terminals may stop working.

Comment: I understand you are chosen VS code to build your project. my updated answer is to resolve your first's issue. but your second issue is your IDE (VS Code). I will be recommended you this link to resolve your second issue:- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/117956

Comment: `@Pritom Sarkar` answer addresses my CORS issues very much thanks

Comment: @Paul glad to know that :)  by the way, this is cors related question, so please accept my answer by clicking the ```RIGHT``` icon.

Answer (score 1):

@Patriom Sarkar's answer addresses your CORS issues/Error

##### In regards to your 401 Unauthorized Responses

Those are likely unrelated to CORS.

What you're having issues with here is that you have configured JwtBearer JSON Web Tokens to be present in requests for your `Authorize` endpoints. It will, by default behavior, use Bearer tokens that are present in your Authorization request header.

Which means, in order to navigate/call `Oper()`, you will need to ensure "Authorization: Bearer {token}" exists with a valid token (as a request header).

Currently, in your `Login` handling, you're generating the token and doing `Set-Cookie` so that the user-agent/client creates 'jwt' cookie with the token as a value; However, the user-agent is not going to automatically add that jwt cookie to the headers of subsequent requests as an Authorization: Bearer Token. So `JwtBearer` configuration on `Authorize` attributed endpoints aren't going to be valid.

Also worth noting, setting the headers in Xhr or Fetch operations is supported and normal in SPA frameworks (to include Cookie stored jwt_tokens).  However, you are not doing Xhr or Fetch requests here, you're doing html form post workflow/mechanic - navigating pages/views. In this respect, setting Authorization Header client-side is (AFAIK) not possible to do.

To support page/view navigation here, you'll need to implement a solution on the server-side that sets the token using the passed `jwt` cookie.

That solution is covered in [In ASP.NET Core read JWT token from Cookie instead of Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52184431/in-asp-net-core-read-jwt-token-from-cookie-instead-of-headers) by @Kirk Larkin

```
    .AddJwtBearer(options => {
            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnMessageReceived = context =>
                {
                    context.Token = context.Request.Cookies["jwt"];
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });
```

##### Additionally

`context.Token` is always `null` or empty in this scope.  No preprocessing nor postprocessing will occur with this declaration and assignment.  If you intend to support Authorization Header and Cookie, you should implement that conditionality in this `OnMessageReceived` assigned delegate.

you can review the default handling of [JwtBearerHandler (aspnetcore 5.0) on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/release/5.0/src/Security/Authentication/JwtBearer/src/JwtBearerHandler.cs).

Thanks again to @Kirk Larkin for providing this additional information in a reply comment on the linked question.

##### Note

This answer was originally provided on a duplicate question: [ASP.NET Core 5.0 JWT authentication is throws 401 code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67865510/asp-net-core-5-0-jwt-authentication-is-throws-401-code/67876141#67876141)

Comment: `@Brett Caswell` Sorry for not expressing my question clearly at the beginning. The question has been revised many times, so I opened a new question

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how relevant this is to the original question but i thought i would chime in.

after struggling for a while on this issue, I ended up adding what @Brett Caswell was saying to solve my problem.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => {
    //add configs
})
.AddJwtBearer(x => {
    //add more configs
    x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnMessageReceived = context =>
                {
                    context.Token = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
            };
})
```

This was after realizing that my JwtAuth scheme was providing tokens but once the token was being sent back for validation, it wasn't hitting anywhere in the startup or configs that i set up for my project. Add this to your .AddJwtBearer() block and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

I try on **asp.net core 6** configured JwtBearer JSON Web Tokens return HTTP 401 code same as before asp.net core 5 error.
but adding what @Brett Caswell was saying to solve my problem.

**code is as follows**

```
.AddJwtBearer(options => {
            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnMessageReceived = context =>
                {
                    context.Token = context.Request.Cookies["jwt"];
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });
```

My asp .net core 6 code 
**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/test/";
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        context.Token = context.Request.Cookies["jwtTest"];
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
                options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JwtTest:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["JwtTest:Issuer"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JwtTest:Key"])

                    )
                };

            });
```

because my app uses cookie-based authentication and JWT bearer authentication so my Controller adds [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes=JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)] for jwt

**HomeController**

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes=JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public ActionResult ShowData()
    {
        var quetTest = dbTestContext.staffTestData.ToList();

        return View("Views/Home/test.cshtml", query);
    }
```