# Why is there no Jwt cookie authentication method for IServiceCollection?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, cookies, jwt, middleware

[Jwt.io](https://jwt.io/introduction) states that tokens are usually passed through the Authorization Header in a HTTP request. My research shows me that storing a JWT in a HTTPOnly cookie is more secure than storing your token in browser storage (session/local). While a JWT stored in a HTTPOnly cookie is still susceptible to CSRF, you can mitigate it with an AntiForgeryToken.

Also, asp.net core provides the `AddJwtBearer()` extension method to configure authentication middleware but it does not provide(from what I can tell) a method to extract a JWT from a HttpOnly cookie.

How can you configure your asp.net core application to extract your JWT token from the cookie? Why is there no Jwt cookie authentication method for IServiceCollection?

Does one have to manually extract the token with custom middleware and add it to the auth header? If so, that seems like a hack.

Comment: 'add it to the auth header?' - why would your backend add anything to the auth header? I think you're misunderstanding what cookies authentication is here. Who is generating the cookie here and who is consuming it? The application authenticates with the server with the cookie, and not with the auth header. You either go with sending the token in the header or using cookies - you don't combine the two if that makes sense?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I said it would add to the auth header because asp.net core only provides the AddJwtBearer extension method, which checks the auth header for the bearer token. The server is generating the cookie and the client(browser) is consuming it. Are you saying that if you use cookie authentication, you don't need to use JWTs?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary It is multiple web apis being accessed through a gateway but a SPA

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary the server is generating the token

Comment: Maybe check the answer in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52184431/in-asp-net-core-read-jwt-token-from-cookie-instead-of-headers

Comment: Storing in localstorage is vulnerable to XSS, storing in http-only cookie is vulnerable to CSRF.  CSRF is not a concern in ASP.NET if you use anti-forgery tokens (which should be included by default)

Comment: @pcalkins That appears to be exactly what I'm looking for. I'm surprised I didn't find that earlier